# Integrating Facebook to post stuff from iPhone app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to implement the functionality of sharing stuff on Facebook in my iPhone app.
After walking through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/
It's giving me some trouble!

I use a singleton class to contain the Facebook object.
When I click the button to share something, the browser opens and I can login to fb.
After that I can press 'okay' and it should redirect me to the app again.
Sadly, I get an error message from safari: 
'Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid'

Obviously it's my first time trying to implement fb in an iOS app....

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a **URL Scheme** for your application so it can be opened from browser/other applications (like Facebook's official one).

This is described in [Step 3: Implementing Single Sign-On (SSO)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso) part of the tutorial you refer to (especially *"Modify the app property list file"* section).

Answer (score 0):

Check the following in your implementation :

1.you need to add the following functions in your application delegate(the facebook object here is your instance value of FaceBook Class).

```
// Pre 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
   return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

// For 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
   return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

2.In your info.plist add to URL types > URL Schemes > your Facebook app ID with fb prefix (finally your value will be like this for ex. fb313714***).